# Find the derivative of $y=\frac{\sin 3x}{\cos 2x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the derivative of $$y=\dfrac{\sin 3x}{\cos 2x}$$ We have $$y'=\dfrac{3\cos 3x\cos 2x+2\sin 2x\sin 3x}{\cos^2 2x}=\dfrac{\frac32\left(\cos x+\cos 5x\right)+\cos x-\cos 5x}{\cos^2 2x}=\\=\dfrac{5\cos x+\cos 5x}{2\cos^2 2x}$$ The answer given in my book is $$y'=\dfrac{\cos 3x\cos 2x+2\cos x}{\cos^2 2x}$$ Am I wrong or are the answers equivalent?

Comment: They [are equivalent](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%285+cos%28x%29%2Bcos%285x%29%29%2F%282+cos%282x%29%5E2%29%3D%28cos%283x%29cos%282x%29%2B2cos%28x%29%29%2Fcos%282x%29%5E2), but your answer is more compact

Answer (score 2):

We can use some cosine formula on the answer in your book (which you already used to get your answer) to get

$ y' = \frac{\frac{1}{2}(\cos{5x}+\cos{x}) + 2\cos{x}}{\cos^{2}{2x}}$

$ y' = \frac{(\cos{5x}+\cos{x}) + 4\cos{x}}{2\cos^{2}{2x}}$

$y' = \frac{5\cos{x} +\cos{5x} }{2\cos^{2}{2x}}$

So they're equivalent.

Comment: Using the formula $\cos a \cdot \cos b = \frac{1}{2}(\cos(a+b)+\cos(a-b))$. The OP already used this formula to simplify his own answer, so I didn't feel the need to include in my answer.